# How to put hover on <img src=""> tag?

Tags: javascript, html

I have some confusions, I want to put hover on image `<img>` tag without using "background-image". So that when user try to mouseover, the image will be change. 
How can i do this?
Thanks.

Comment: It's just an advice but the reason it is better to use css is that it is easier to change the image afterwards, you only need to change the css file, not some javascript's hardcoded value.

Comment: I dont want to use "background-image"

Comment: check this out.. if you are looking out for https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/demos/detail/image-navigation-menu-tabs

Answer (score 29):

## 1. Inline JavaScript version

```
<img src="a.jpg" onmouseover="this.src='b.jpg'" onmouseout="this.src='a.jpg'" />
```

`this` refer to the current `img` tag

## 2. CSS Version (recommended)

#### CSS

```
a.logo {
  display:block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: url(/path/to/logo.png) no-repeat center center;
  background-size: contain;
}

a.logo:hover {
  background-image: url(/path/to/logo-hover.png);
}
```

#### HTML

```
<a href="#" class="logo"></a>
```

By using css, you get more flexibility and it will work even on JavaScript-Disabled environments.

## 3. JavaScript handler

Useful on advanced situations

```
var img = document.getElementById('myImg');

img.onmouseout = function () {
   this.src = 'b.jpg';
};

img.onmouseover = function () {
   this.src = 'a.jpg';
};
```

Comment: Make sure your codes are inside code blocks, use ctrl+k. Or Select the "{}" image in the editor.

Answer (score 10):

Inline version: `<img src="original.jpg" onmouseover="this.src='hover.jpg';" onmouseout="this.src='original.jpg';" />`

Answer (score 4):

```
$(function() {
  $("img")
    .mouseover(function() { 
        var src = $(this).attr("src").match(/[^\.]+/) + "over.gif";
        $(this).attr("src", src);
    })
    .mouseout(function() {
        var src = $(this).attr("src").replace("over", "");
        $(this).attr("src", src);
    });
 });
```

To set up on ready:

Answer (score 1):

```css
img:hover {
  background: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/7KXRp.jpg");
  /* padding: [image-height] [image-width] 0 0 */
  padding: 200px 200px 0 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/9OcHP.jpg" />
```