# span image hover in css?

Tags: html, css

Hello friends. I want to change the image on hover but my code is not working.

Code so far

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
a.rollover span.displace {
    display: block;
    width: 150px;
    height: 44px;
    text-decoration: none;
    }

a.rollover span.displace img:hover {
    background: url("images/red.png");
    display: block;
    }


</style>
<body>
<a href="#" class="rollover" title="Webvamp"><span class="displace"><img src="images/blue.png"/></a>


</body>
</html>
```

Any help is highly appreciated...

Comment: Could you be more specific about the problem than "not workd"? What happens when you try it, and how does that differ from what you expect?

Comment: for better result use background image only like `a.rollover span.displace` use background-image and small edit in `a.rollover span.displace img:hover` use `a.rollover span.displace:hover` rest remain same in this class

Comment: You have not closed the span tag in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code below should work.
CSS:

```
<style>
a.rollover span.displace {
    display: block;
    width: 150px;
    height: 44px;
    text-decoration: none;
     background: url("images/blue.png");
}

a.rollover span.displace:hover {
    background: url("images/red.png");        
}
</style>
```

And HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="rollover" title="Webvamp"><span class="displace"></span></a>
```

You are trying to place a background for an image which shows another image, so basically your background is hidden below image which is specified with src

---

If you want to have img - you can use solution from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9782469/1558311) answer:

```
<a href="#" class="rollover" title="Webvamp"><span class="displace"><img src="images/blue.png" onmouseover="this.src='images/red.png';" onmouseout="this.src='images/blue.png';"/></span></a>
```

---

Another option would be:

```
<a href="#" class="rollover" title="Webvamp"><span class="displace"><img src="images/blue.png" class="initial" /><img src="images/red.png" class="hover"/> </span></a>
```

And CSS:

```
img.hover{display:none;}

a.rollover span.displace {
    display: block;
    width: 150px;
    height: 44px;
    text-decoration: none;        
}

a.rollover span.displace:hover img.hover{
    display:block;      
}

a.rollover span.displace:hover img.initial{
    display:none;      
}
```

Comment: but my image is coming from span and i want to change this image on hover

Comment: Does it makes any difference if you will have an img tag or your image will be shown because it is specified as background image of a span? If you just need to see an image and change it on hover - you can use css solution I've posted. Otherwise - see my answer. There is a link to an answer which allows to change img src on hover with pure JS

Comment: Suppose if image comes from span ...then what i can do, I do not want to use javascript... I want to change img by hover

Comment: See updated answer. There you need two images. One is hidden by default, but is shown when hovered. And initial image is hidden (Ooops... I need to add that last thing) )

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is somewhat not clear. What you're trying to do is you are trying to set a background image, for an image, it'll be set but not shown because your image will overlap the element's background image.

Try this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<style>

a.rollover span.displace div.image, a.rollover span.displace  {
    display: block;
    width: 150px;
    height: 44px;
    text-decoration: none;
    }

a.rollover span.displace div.image {
    background: url("images/blue.png");
}

a.rollover span.displace div.image:hover {
    background: url("images/red.png");
    }

</style>

<body>

<a href="#" class="rollover" title="Webvamp">

    <span class="displace">

        <div class="image"></div>

    </span>

</a>

</body>

</html>
```

In this code, what I have done is I have taken a `div` and set a background image for it. When someone hovers over that `div`, the CSS changes `div`'s background image, and changes it back when the user withdraws his cursor from the `div`.

Comment: actually image is coming through span and i want to hover it

Comment: I have edited my code now. I hope this is what you're looking for