# How to display an image in a different spot on hover when using image links with HTML and CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, hover, mouseover

I have six images that are links (my main nav) and I want them each to display a different image (in a different spot on the page) when they are hovered over. Can this be done in HTML and CSS alone? Or will I need JavaScript? Here's my code. Thanks in advance.

```
    <div id="mainnav">
        <div id="gdpbutton">
            <a href="gdp.html"><img id="gdpImg" src="images/GDP-button.png"/></a>
        </div>

        <div id="gdwbutton">
            <a href="gdw.html"><img id="gdwImg" src="images/GDW-button.png"/></a>
        </div>

        <div id="wdmbutton">
            <a href="wdm.html"><img id="wdmImg" src="images/WDM-button.png"/></a>
        </div>

        <div id="wddbutton">
            <a href="wdd.html"><img id="wddImg" src="images/WDD-button.png"/></a>
        </div>

        <div id="webdevbutton">
            <a href="webdev.html"><img id="webdevImg" src="images/WEBDEV-button.png"/></a>
        </div>

        <div id="miscbutton">
            <a href="misc.html"><img id="miscImg" src="images/MISC-button.png"/></a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here is the image of my homepage with the image links I'm talking about. When you hover over one of those links, I want a different image to appear in the middle circle in the middle of all the image links. Hope this helps you guys understand what I'm trying to do. Thank you!

[homepage image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eCJwi.jpg)

Comment: if you need to switch between to image on `hover` it possible on css and html . but on the other case you probebly need javascript

Comment: Possible duplicate of :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9782328/how-to-put-hover-on-img-src-tag

Answer (score 0):

I think this might solve your problem using css alone. Find this link [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/praveentpt/ZSZQK/1199/)

```
#hover 
{
 display: none;
}
#image:hover + #hover 
{
 display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi if you want to display the image only in hover,
Instead of giving in the image in HTML itself, You can give in CSS like:

### .gdwbutton : hover { background-image:url("images/GDP-button.png"); }

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this example code:

```
#mainnav{
  width:170px;
  height:20px;
}
#mainnav > div{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
}
#mainnav:hover #gdpbutton{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0px;
}

#mainnav:hover #gdwbutton{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:50px;
} 
#mainnav:hover  #wdmbutton{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:80px;
} 
#mainnav:hover  #wddbutton{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:110px;
} 
#mainnav:hover #webdevbutton {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:140px;
} 
#mainnav:hover #miscbutton{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:170px;
} 
img{
  max-width:100%;
}
```

[demo](http://jsbin.com/pirogogapo/edit?html,css,output)

Answer (score 0):

[JsFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/refan/x00ojuz0/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#mainnav a img").each(function(index, element) {
    // element == this

    $(element).hover(function() {
      var src = $(this).attr("src");
      $("#msg").text(src);
      $("#image").attr("src", src);
    });


    $(element).mouseout(function() {
      $("#image").attr("src", "");
    })

  });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

If you need the image hover and positioning to be dynamic then you will need to use Javascript. If you have only 6 images then you can do it by CSS. Your question is not much clear on the scenario and exactly what you want to achieve. So we can not give you any solution in codes.

Comment: you can ask this question with comment. It is not a answer

Comment: @SercanTimoçin OP asked if he can achieve the solution with HTML-CSS or he need to use Javascript. So this answers his question and as even you agree there is not much info on the issue. Relax my dear friend, there was no personal vendetta :)