# Show image on mouseover in Markdown

Tags: markdown, github-flavored-markdown

I was wondering if it's possible at all to display a linked image in a tooltip/popover in vanilla or GitHub Flavored Markdown.

I imagine this would be helpful for showing linked images to simplify markdown length. [Tappy](https://github.com/python-tap/tappy) comes to mind.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

John Gruber's original [Markdown](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/)

> is two things: (1) a plain text formatting syntax; and (2) a software tool, written in Perl, that converts the plain text formatting to HTML.

It is firmly concerned with *content*, not presentation.

However, it supports [inline HTML](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#html), so if you already have an image that you want to change and you're willing to write something like [`<img src="a.jpg" onmouseover="this.src='b.jpg'" onmouseout="this.src='a.jpg'" />`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9782446/354577) you should be able to make this work.

You can experiment with inline HTML to bring in external CSS or JS if you want a different effect.

GitHub Flavored Markdown [is a different story](https://github.com/github/markup#github-markup). After HTML is generated from the Markdown input it

> is sanitized, aggressively removing things that could harm you and your kin—such as `script` tags, inline-styles, and `class` or `id` attributes. See the [sanitization filter](https://github.com/jch/html-pipeline/blob/master/lib/html/pipeline/sanitization_filter.rb) for the full whitelist.

This process will almost certainly remove whatever mouseover technique you try.